Switch the order of a single summation
I'm trying to proof this seemingly trivial formula, which states that the order of a summation doesn't matter:
\begin{equation}
\forall a,n \in \mathbb{Z}:\qquad \sum_{i=a}^{n} f(i) = \sum_{i=a}^{n}f(n+a-i)
\end{equation}
The sums are trivial for the cases $a>n$ and $a=n$.
So for $a<n$ I tried to use double induction:

Inductionstart for $n = 0$:
\begin{equation}
\forall a \in \mathbb{Z}_{<0}:\qquad \sum_{i=a}^{0} f(i) = \sum_{i=a}^{0}f(a-i)
\end{equation}
I proofed this by Induction with the start $a=-1$ and the step $a \longrightarrow a-1$.

Inductionhypothesis
\begin{equation}
\forall a,n \in \mathbb{Z}, \qquad a<n:\qquad \sum_{i=a}^{n} f(i) = \sum_{i=a}^{n}f(n+a-i)
\end{equation}

Inductionstep
\begin{equation}
\forall a,n \in \mathbb{Z},\qquad a<n:\qquad \sum_{i=a}^{n\pm 1} f(i) = \sum_{i=a}^{n \pm 1}f(n \pm 1+a-i)
\end{equation}
Since $n$ can be negative too I need to proof both the plus and minus 1 step.

Inductionproof
Lets proof $n \longrightarrow n +1$ first:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=a}^{n+1} f(i) &= f(n+1) + \sum_{i=a}^{n} f(i)\\
&=f(n+1)+\sum_{i=a}^{n}f(n+a-i) \\
&=f(n+1)+\sum_{i=a-1}^{n-1}f(n+1+a-i) \\
&=f(n+1)+f(n+1+a-(a-1))+\sum_{i=a}^{n-1}f(n+1+a-i) \\
&=f(n+1)+f(n+2)+\sum_{i=a}^{n-1}f(n+1+a-i) \\
&=f(n+1)+f(n+2)-f(n+1+a-n)+\sum_{i=a}^{n}f(n+1+a-i) \\
&=f(n+1)+f(n+2)-f(a+1)+\sum_{i=a}^{n}f(n+1+a-i) \\
&=f(n+1)+f(n+2)-f(a+1)-f(n+1+a-(n+1))+\sum_{i=a}^{n+1}f(n+1+a-i) \\
&=f(n+1)+f(n+2)-f(a+1)-f(a)+\sum_{i=a}^{n+1}f(n+1+a-i) \\
\end{align}
But these extra terms are obviously false. For the negative case I get similarily wrong results. Where did I go wrong?

Edit:
As pointed out in the comments, the mistake was in the index shift:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=a}^{n+1} f(i) &= f(n+1) + \sum_{i=a}^{n} f(i)\\
&=f(n+1)+\sum_{i=a}^{n}f(n+a-i) \\
&=f(n+1)+\sum_{i=a+1}^{n+1}f(n+a-(i-1)) \\
&=f(n+1)+\sum_{i=a+1}^{n+1}f(n+1+a-i)) \\
&=f(n+1)-f(n+1+a-a)+\sum_{i=a}^{n+1}f(n+1+a-i) \\
&=f(n+1)-f(n+1)+\sum_{i=a}^{n+1}f(n+1+a-i) \\
&=\sum_{i=a}^{n+1}f(n+1+a-i) \\
\end{align}
The negative case worked out nicely too now.
This would answers my question. However, the overall structure of my proof has been criticized too. And I don't know where I implemented the double induction structure incorrectly?

First, your "induction hypothesis" and "induction step" should not be quantified over $n$. Then, $\sum_{i=a}^{n}f(n+a-i)\ne\sum_{i=a-1}^{n-1}f(n+1+a-i)$.

@AnneBauval But if I make my "induction start" with $n=0$ than I can't just switch to $a \longrightarrow a +1$ in the middle of the proof.

Can we first (by change of index) reduce to the case $a=0$?

You don't need to "switch to $a⟶a+1$
in the middle of the proof".

The third equality seems very wrong. Whence all the wrong terms.

@TedShifrin Do you mean by "reduce to the case $a=0$" this: $\sum_{i=a}^{n} f(n+a-i)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-a} f(n-i)$?

@AnneBauval Could you explain further? I still don't really understand whats wrong with the structure of my proof.

I meant to deal with only the case $a=0$ from the very beginning. Then the extra degree of freedom is handled by considering $f(k+i)$ from the outset.

Again: your fundamental mistake lies in quantifying over $n$ inside the statement of the induction hypothesis and then inside the statement of the induction step. What you should do instead is: "induction hypothesis: let $n\in\Bbb Z$ be such that $\forall a<n\dots$" and "induction step: let us prove that (for this $n$) $\forall  a<n+1\dots$ and $\forall  a<n-1\dots$ ".

@AnneBauval Ok this is much better than what I wrote, thanks!

You have made this far more complicated than it needs to be. This actually doesn't have anything to do with sums, just about different ways to parametrize the set of integers
$$
[a, n] = \{ i \in \mathbb{Z} \mid a \leq i \leq n \} 
$$
for $a \leq n$.
You have to convince yourself that the map $\varphi: [a, n] \to [a, n]$ that reverses the list given by $\varphi(i) = a + n - i$ is a bijection. It suffices to observe that it is its own inverse, since
$$
\varphi\bigl(\varphi(i)\bigr) = \varphi(a + n - i) 
= a + n - (a + n - i)
= i
$$
for all $i \in [a, n]$.

+1 Thats a nice idea, but my question was more about the double induction technique.

I disagree that it doesn't have anything to do with sums.  Your proof is assuming a theorem about sums, that $\sum_{i=a}^n a_n = \sum_{i=a}^n a_{\phi(n)}$ for a bijection $\phi: [a,n] \to [a,n]$.  Proving that would require induction.

That's fair, @JairTaylor. Commutativity and associativity, with induction on the number of summands.
